# Automatically lock screen, but do not go to sleep, when lid is closed

Tags: sleep-wake, monitoring, macbook-pro

In a similar, but not duplicate, vein to [Listening to music with MacBooks lid closed](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/366128/listening-to-music-with-macbooks-lid-closed/366131), I'd like to be able to listen to music with my 2019 MacBook Pro's lid closed. But I can't accept the compromise of losing the automatic screen lock by simply having the MacBook not go to sleep.

In contrast, if I activate screen lock manually (I have it mapped to the Touch Bar, so through whatever mechanism that is), my music keeps playing. I can play/pause it using the touchbar or my Bluetooth headphones and control volume this way too. This is exactly the experience I want to have, but I want to be able to have it with the lid closed.

It would appear that `pmset`, which is what lets you disable sleep on lid close, is not the only family of tools I want here, because it is about managing power states and not about monitoring any hardware events per se. I don't really care what power state my MacBook is in when the lid is closed. (I mean I hope it's not hogging the battery too bad just playing some audio, but I don't have any hard drives I'm worried about being in use while moving it around or anything like that - it doesn't need to be asleep and I trust it to not burn itself up that way because this is a nice operating system.) I just want lid close to trigger a screen lock, basically, and also not a sleep.

Under Linux-y type environments this can be achieved (not sure how but I know there are lid events for dbus, which is part of the backbone of all modern Linux display managers), but I'm clueless as to how to achieve this particular thing.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the free and open source tool [KeepingYouAwake](https://keepingyouawake.app) for keeping the MacBook from going to sleep when you close the lid.

Comment: This doesn't achieve my goal - see [this issue](https://github.com/newmarcel/KeepingYouAwake/issues/165) on the KeepingYouAwake GitHub - it describes that KeepingYouAwake doesn't let the screen lock as a side-effect of display sleeping, which is a requirement for me.